# zsh: inconsistent error handling in assignments

Tags: zsh, variable, variable-substitution, process-substitution

This is `zsh -f`:

```
Fereidoons-MacBook-Pro% local a=$(jaja) && echo bad
zsh: command not found: jaja
bad
Fereidoons-MacBook-Pro% a=$(jaja) && echo bad
zsh: command not found: jaja
Fereidoons-MacBook-Pro%
```

Why is `local` messing up error handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `zsh` manual regarding the `typeset` builtin (which `local` is a special case of):

> Unlike parameter assignment statements, `typeset`'s exit status on
>   an assignment that involves a command substitution does not
>   reflect the exit status of the command substitution.  Therefore,
>   to test for an error in a command substitution, separate the
>   declaration of the parameter from its initialization:
>
> ```
>   # WRONG
>    typeset var1=$(exit 1) || echo "Trouble with var1"
>
>   # RIGHT
>    typeset var1 && var1=$(exit 1) || echo "Trouble with var1"
> ```

In your case:

```
$ unset a
$ local a=$(jaja) && echo bad
zsh: command not found: jaja
bad
```

```
$ unset a
$ local a && a=$(jaja) && echo bad
zsh: command not found: jaja
```